# jQuery "this" changing in chain

Tags: jquery

I have a div that has a div  inside it that will delete the outer div when clicked.  The jQuery to make this happen is

```
275 $(document).on('click','.rightMenuDelete', function(event) {
276   $(this).parents('.cell').  
277   fadeOut(300, function()  {
278     $(this).remove();});
279  });
```

At 276 the this keyword is the inner div we clicked.  By 277 the wrapped set has the outer div we want to delete.  But I want to fade out the outer div before I remove it, so 277 applies the fadeOut and then the callback removes the outer div.  What surprises me a bit is that 278 works.  The this keyword at 278 is  the outer div, as we want , and no longer the inner div that we clicked originally.  Can anyone throw some light on how the this keyword can change as control moves down a jQuery chain?

Thanks

Comment: Some relevant code would be helpful...

Comment: You're using it inside of a different function. Different functions can have different contexts. What is there to explain?

Comment: You did select the parent `.cell` elements, and then attached a new function, with a new scope, to that selector.

Comment: I ddn't get a chance to answer before others, but i started [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/VxDth/) before you posted your code just to give you a basic demo of what you're trying to achieve. Good Luck!  
http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/VxDth/

Comment: Keven B:  In JavaScript, the this keyword in a function is the global object, like window or document, which clearly isn't what it refers to here. So it appears that jQuery is doing some slight-of-hand to get this to be the results of the last selector. It's that process that I was trying to get a better understanding of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element pointed to by `this` changes on line 276 itself, when `parents('.cell')` is executed. It no longer points to the `inner` div, but to the list of parents with the class `cell`.

After which you execute the fadeOut which loops over the collection of parents. Inside the loop, `this` refers to the current parent being looped over.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a reference to your old `this`, because here you're calling `.fadeOut` on `.parents('.cell')`

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding.  He's saying the code works as intended and wants to know why.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in Javascript is scoped based on the function that it is in.  Create a variable that you pass into the callback and call `.remove` on it.

```
$(document).on('click','.rightMenuDelete', function(event) {
    var par = $(this).parents('.cell');
    par.fadeout(300, function() {$(par).remove();});
  });
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the original `this` you can save it in a variable:

```
$(document).on('click','.rightMenuDelete', function(event) {
   var that = this;
   $(this).parents('.cell').  
       fadeOut(300, function()  {
           $(that).remove();});
});
```

The above technique is required because `this` changes context inside the fadeOut as noted by the other responses.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone.  You guys are great, and quick. Assigning the parent to a variable and then using that variable in the fadeOut/remove line is clearly better coding, and I will do that. My main question, though, was what was happening in the jQuery to get the value of the this keyword to change from one function to the next inside the jQuery chain.  In pure JavaScript the this keyword inside of a function is the global object, like window or document, and clearly something more is happening here.

I understand now, though, that the this passed to the callback function is current member of the wrapped set passed to it, and the wrapped set at this point is the parent, not the original clickee. Thanks again.