# Comparing $this selector with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a website with Flask server side that monitors data built on other build machines I have running. On the monitoring page I have the current status of specific machines which I update every few seconds. I would like to be able to mouse over the names of certain machines and a tooltip will pop up displaying the current data it is building. I currently have the functionality built in to store the data server side in a database and poll the database. But as of now it returns ALL of the status of the data. I am okay with this but I can't differentiate which element it is on so I can't display the correct data. In my mouseover function I have an ajax call and in the success function I information of current DOM element I am over.

```
$('.target').mouseover(function() {
  $.getJSON('/_get_platform', {
    statusID: {{ statusID }}
            }, function(data) {
    var $this=$(this);
    var $tip=$($this.attr('data-tooltip'));
  }); //end getjson
}); //end mouseover
```

I am tying to compare $tip to (for example) the id #debugTip. So if I know the mouse is on the element with id debugTip then I can display the appropriate data associated with this element.

(I have taking away all of the extraneous code like tooltips etc... for brevity)

Could anyone tell me how I can compare this to something I know? I've tried using $tip == '#debugTip' and $tip.is('#debugTip') but either that didn't work or I am not using it correctly. Anyone know what my mistake is?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery "this" changing in chain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364352/jquery-this-changing-in-chain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have access to `this` until before you do the ajax request. So you have to store the tip before going into that ajax callback.

```
$('.target').on( 'mouseover', function() {

  // get the tip, while we still have 'this' object (before the ajax)
  var $tip = $($(this).data('tooltip'));

  $.getJSON('/_get_platform', {
    statusID: {{ statusID }}
  }, function(data) {

    // check if it's a debug tooltip
    if ( $tip.is('#debugTip') ) {
      console.log("it's the debug tip");
    } else {
      console.log("normal tooltip");
    }

  }); //end getjson  
}); //end mouseover
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to check wether or not the $('.target') element has the "#debugTip" ID, then you can do:

```
if($tip.is("#debugTip")){
    console.log('Debug data here');
}
```

Comment: `this` isn't a dom element inside the callback, so therefore neither is `$this`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to refer the element which the mouse hovered on, you need to save it in a variable and then you can refer it in the callback of the $.getJSON.

```js
$('.target').mouseover(function() {
                        var mouseOveredElement = $(this);
                        $.getJSON('/_get_platform', {
                              statusID: {{ statusID }}
                        }, function(data) {
                              var tip=$(mouseOveredElement).attr('data-tooltip');
                        }); //end getjson
                     });    //end mouseover
```

Comment: By the way, you $.getJSON function fetched some 'data' in the callback and your code seems not utilising that 'data'. Not sure, maybe some code left out?

Comment: The way you're using `mouseOveredElement` inside the `$.getJSON()` callback isn't correct - you'll likely want to do `var $tip = $(mouseOveredElement.data('tooltip'));` instead.

Comment: @JamesPederson Nothing wrong to use in my way. checkout here: https://jsfiddle.net/pengyanb/1zL33cb0/3/

Comment: @JamesPederson Ahh, I know what you talking about now. You are referring the first $ sign which I forgot to remove from his original code. Thanks. Made the change now.

Comment: Still need the $ before that open paren if you want to actually select the tooltip object.

Comment: @JamesPederson $(mouseOveredElement).attr('data-tooltip'); is the way. See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pengyanb/1zL33cb0/3/